# Proving that $n$ is a Carmichael number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Determine if the statement is, in general, true or false. Recall that a universal statement is true if it is true for all possible cases while it is false if there is even one counterexample. Be prepared to prove that your answer is correct by supplying a proof or counterexample, whichever is appropriate.

Suppose that $m>0$ and that $4m+1$, $8m+1$, and $12m+1$ are prime. Then $n=(4m+1)(8m+1)(12m+1)$ is a Carmichael number.

---

*Solution*:

In order to prove that $n$ is a Carmichael number we need to verify that $n-1$ is divisible by the LCM of $4m$, $12m$, and $8m$, that is, $24m|n-1$.

Consider $(4m+1)(8m+1)(12m+1)=384m^3+176m^2+24m+1$ so that
$$n-1=8m(48m^2+22m+3)=8m\cdot f(m)\qquad(*)$$

Hence, $n$ is a Carmichael number.

Could you check it for me please, is it correct or not?

Comment: Your proposition is a particular case of the main theorem of the following article: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1939-45-04/S0002-9904-1939-06953-X/S0002-9904-1939-06953-X.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. The number $(4m+1)(8m+1)(12m+1)\ $ is a Carmichael number, if all the three factors are prime because $4m$ , $8m$ and $12m$ divide $(4m+1)(8m+1)(12m+1)-1$

Note, that you get more Carmichael numbers if you use $(6m+1)(12m+1)(18m+1)$. This number is also Carmichael, whenever the three factors are prime.

Since your triples must satisfy $3|m$ (otherwise one of the factors is divisible by $3$), they are of the form $12m+1$ , $24m+1$ , $36m+1$, so
you miss the triples $6m+1/12m+1/18m+1$ with odd $m$.